# Postgres Updating only changed columns as against entire row

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table like below

```
CREATE TABLE empl(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   address VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   status int NOT NULL,
   metadata varchar NOT NULL
);
```

and it has data like

```
(ID, NAME, ADDRESS, STATUS, METADATA)
(2,  'tuk', 'ind',    1,      'meta')
...
(200,'tuka','eng',    2,      'meta2')
```

1. `update empl set status = 2 where (id = 2);`
2. `update empl set status = 2, name='tuk', address='ind',  metadata='meta'  where (id = 2);`

Can someone let me know if there are any advantages of doing #1 over #2? Which is generally preferred?

Postgres Version - 10.17

Comment: Please clarify...  Are you asking if there's an advantage to specifying `SET`s for fields that aren't changing?  If so, then I don't believe there is.  Specifying additional `SET` fields increases the "width" of the query and decreases performance.  As such, your first query would be preferable.  That said, there is, at times, an advantage to including additional `WHERE` constraints to ensure that one is editing only the desired row, such as with manual changes; e.g., `UPDATE empl SET status = 2 WHERE id = 2 AND name = 'tuk'`.  What benefit do you perceive from the second query?

Comment: Which rows do you want to update? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: I only want to update the `status` field for id = 2. In the second query, I am updating the entire row even though all the values are same except for `status`  whereas in first case I am updating only  the column that is changing, `status`. Is there any advantage / disadvantages in both the queries over one another?

Comment: *Postgres Updating only changed columns as against entire row* The slowest operation during UPDATE is saving data changes to disk. The server saves the whole row (more precisely - the block which contains this row), and no difference does one column was changed or all of them. So there is no any advantage. More precisely - it exists, but no chance to detect it, the difference will be less than time measurement accuracy.

Comment: postgresql is an mvcc base and never actually does an in-place update. It's always creating a new version of the row and marking the old one as deleted. Both of your queries will behave more like insert+delete than update

Comment: @Melkij - what happens in case of index and triggers? Does postgres figure out that there is no change in column value and do not update the index or invoke the trigger?

Comment: Postgresql does not check for value differences. You can use the ` suppress_redundant_updates_trigger` trigger for this.

Comment: @Melkij Ok so that means postgres will update the indices also if the updated field is part of an index even if the updated value is same as the previous one?

Comment: Correct. Much more confusing if the HOT update optimization was used. But generally correct. Indexes point to TID - a specific row position in the datafile block. Since we write a different version of the row when updating, we get a different TID. And so we need to add this TID to the index so that the index can find this row.

Comment: Thanks @Melkij all these were helpful info. Can you please post these also as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the discussion from the comments in the question

> postgresql is an mvcc base and never actually does an in-place update.
> It's always creating a new version of the row and marking the old one
> as deleted. Both of your queries will behave more like insert+delete
> than update.
>
> Postgresql does not check for value differences. So that means
> postgres will update the indices also if the updated field is part of
> an index even if the updated value is same as the previous one. But
> much more confusing if the HOT update optimization was used. But
> generally correct. Indexes point to TID - a specific row position in
> the datafile block. Since we write a different version of the row when
> updating, we get a different TID. And so we need to add this TID to
> the index so that the index can find this row.
>
> Both the queries will cause triggers to be fired if it effects some
> columns with triggers. However,
> [suppress_redundant_updates_trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-trigger.html) may be used to suppress
> redundant update if there is no actual change in data.